# how to take n objects from database without fetching all the objects in nhibernate

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

how to take n objects from database without fetching all the objects in nhibernate?

Here is an example

suppose that I have this domain entity

```
public class Contract
{
    Ilist<Asset> Assets{get; set;}
}

public class Asset
{
    Ilist<Contract> Contracts{get; set;}
}
```

in the above example I have many to many relationship and If I have a query lik this

```
IList<Asset> = contract.Assets.take(10);
```

in this case it will bring all the assets from the database and then it will take 10 of them sow how can I in someway to force the developers to not use `contract.Assets` directly and to to tell the nhibernate to only bring those 10 elements directly from the dtatabase

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<Asset> = contract.Assets.take(10);
```

Is not a query, it's just accessing a property that is a IList or rather a Proxy. As i know, you can't do this like you want. You have to query against the database like this:

```
Session.Query<Asset>().Where(a => a.Contracts.Any(c => c.Id == myContractId)).Take(10);
```